# Where is ken burns effect in iMovie 10.0.7?

Tags: imac, imovie

I'm not finding the ken burns effect any more in iMovie 10.0.7. Is it not included anymore? Went to "crop", nothing there this time but crop itself. No more "adjust" tool either.

Where are you, Ken Burns?

Answer (score 1):

Ken Burns is between the toolbar & output picture  [I don't really use iMovie, but that's where I would expect it to be from using Final Cut]

[image]

I'm not sure which 'adjust' tool you mean.

Comment: I can confirm, same thing in iMovie.